# Get twitter and google plus share count or any alternate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, twitter

Hi I have tried below code for twitter.

```
var tw_share_count = 0;
TWUrl = "https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=" + url + '&callback=?'
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: TWUrl,
    success: function (data) {
        tw_share_count = data.count.toString();
        alert(tw_share_count);
    },
    async: false
});
```

And below code for google share count

var gl_shares_count = 0;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js',
    processData: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'method': 'pos.plusones.get',
        'id': url,
        'params': {
        'nolog': true,
        'id': url,
        'source': 'widget',
        'userId': '@viewer',
        'groupId': '@self'
    },
    'jsonrpc': '2.0',
    'key': 'p',
    'apiVersion': 'v1'
    }),
    success: function (response) {  
        alert(response.result.metadata.globalCounts.count);
        //  $('a.googleplus .counter').text(response.result.metadata.globalCounts.count);
    }
});
```

In had checked in some of the sight and they are saying that both twitter and google + has stopped sharing count.
I dont know how much it is true.

I am able to share the link but not able to have count.
My Facebook and Pinterest count is coming very well but twitter and google plus count is not coming

**Please get me rid of this issue or give me the alternate for this that is easy and free to implement.**

For test I am using some random site to get the exact data for twitter/ google+ count like https://draxe.com/emotions-lower-inflammation/

Comment: This is true, Twitter no longer provides share counts and the endpoint your code is calling was never intended or documented for public consumption. Twitter's API provides no alternative to get this data.

Comment: @AndyPiper what about google plus?

Comment: I have no idea about Google Plus, sorry.

Comment: @AndyPiper for twitter I had also heard that there provide 3rd party tool as per doc https://marketingland.com/twitter-share-numbers-159379

Comment: Sure, if you want to trust any of those you are free to try them out, up to you. I was answering in the context of Twitter's own support for the feature, which no longer exists (and was not completely accurate anyway) https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/a/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform.html

Comment: Did you get the answer to this?
I am also looking for the similar api or something so I can show it on the webpage.

Comment: @kirtan not yet

Comment: @MiteshJain, i found some third party js, and modified little bit, take a look,  may be this will help u

Comment: Please read this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/xtV65mHlymM, https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/cR-XHCynEJA google plus also no longer provides share counts

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this, i got a third party js to get social count. May be this will help you

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://webcyou.github.io/social-share-count-js/js/social-share-count.js"></script>
  <title>Share Count</title>
  <style>
.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.fa-google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}


.fa-pinterest {
  background: #cb2027;
  color: white;
}

.fa-yahoo {
  background: #430297;
  color: white;
}
p{
 font-size:14px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook">
 <p data-sc-fb="http://www.eventbee.com"></p>
</a>

<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter">
 <p data-sc-tw="https://stackoverflow.com"></p>
</a>

<a href="#" class="fa fa-google">
 <p data-sc-gp="http://www.webcyou.com"></p>
</a>

<a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest">
 <p data-sc-pr="https://www.google.com/"></p>
</a>

<a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin">
 <p data-sc-ln="https://www.yahoo.com/"></p>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: even twitter is not working from my end. I had tried putting link as  https%3A%2F%2Fdraxe.com%2Femotions-lower-inflammation%2F   and   https://draxe.com/emotions-lower-inflammation/  I had tried both link but it is not showing the count

Comment: you can also try sharing upper link and can test from your end